# Setting .change function on dropdown in iFrame using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working and what I need to do to get this to work?

```
$("#rptframe").contents()
              .find('#customerjax')
              .change(function () { alert("yeah"); })
              .change();
```

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: try replacing your last `.change();` with `.trigger('change');`

Comment: Assuming that the element `#customerjax` is capable of firing a `change` event, of course

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxuCd/). Your problem is basically that you do not access the elements in the Iframe. You have to use `.contentWindow.document` on the Iframe element to drill down into the frame content.

This should probably work:

```
$($("#rptframe")[0].contentWindow.document)
    .find('#customerjax')
    .change(function () { alert("yeah"); })
    .change();
```